# CMakeList set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

If I run

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/rip/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake
```

everything works well. But if I write

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/rip/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake")
```

in the `CMakeLists.txt` and run only cmake, the error message below is shown:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick" with any
  of the following names:

   Qt5QuickConfig.cmake
   qt5quick-config.cmake
```

This is the complete code:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -O3 -fopenmp")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/rip/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake")

project(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCES main.cpp Test5.cpp )
set(HAEDERS Test5.h )
set(RESOURCES qml.qrc )

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HAEDERS} ${RESOURCES}) 
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $,$>:QT_QML_DEBUG>) 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)
```

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` from the `CMakeLists.txt` should work. Please, show **more code**: how your setting is placed relative to `project()` call and to `find_package()` call.

Comment: Hm, this setting should work. You may try to move `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ...)` after the `project()` call. Side notes: current setting of variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` definitely doesn't work, you need to move it after the `project()` call. Also, you code lacks for `cmake_minimum_required()` call. Usually, CMake emits a warning about this, so it is better to fix that.

Comment: Oh i found the error. It was a problem with Clion. Now all works fine. Thank you very much. But the 'CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS' works fine before the project().

Comment: I have same issue with xtensor library setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH inside CMakeList.txt does not help but outside works well

Comment: @Orion How did you work around this Clion issue?

Answer (score 50):

The prefix path is a list of paths. Use this:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/rip/Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64")
```

Also you don't have to point directly into the config file path, you also can point into the directory containing the `lib/cmake/...`

Comment: This worked for me. I am new to cmake and I wasted half an hour believing this does not work, only to find that the reason it didnt work was because I had a typo in my path (!), and cmake gave no warning about invalid path.

Comment: @ThammeGowda The point of telling CMake to find package or find library is that the paths may or may not exist, I don't think it should warn about a non existent path ;)

Answer (score 4):

For me @guillaume-racicot's suggstion doesn't work. The CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is set, but everything that's on it is ignored.

I found out that you can access the environment variable, split that into a list and append to that to actually *append* to the prefix path instead of replacing it.

```
# Create a list by replacing colon with semicolon
string(REPLACE ":" ";" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
# Append to the newly created list
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "<YOUR_ADDITIONAL_SEARCH_PATH>")
```

Comment: That's weird. On what environment are you? It almost look like a bug to not treat it as a list in the first place.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with cmake 3.10.2. As far as I can tell, it's not that it's not treated as a list, but instead that `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is empty, while `$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}` (the environment variable) is not, and in order to get anything that's on the environment variable, I need to first convert that string to a list.

Comment: Make sure you reproduce that in an otherwise empty CMake file. A file containing only `cmake_minimum_required(3.14 REQUIRED) project(test123) message("${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")`. If you played with the prefix path or use toolchain file, it could be empty. If you use a toolchain file, I would advice *not* setting it back.