# open62541: Linker Tool Error for referenced functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, linker, open62541

I am trying to get open62541 to work on my Windows 10 machine, but even with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), I am still struggling.

**Goal**

I want to execute a cpp OPC_UA Client with all associated functionalities (CRUD on PLC Variables and so on).

**Current status**

I already built the open62541 project according to the official [docs](https://open62541.org/doc/current/building.html) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985518/build-open62541-dll-with-visual-studio-2017):

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -UA_NAMESPACE_ZERO=FULL ..
```

After that I ran ALL_BUILD and INSTALL without any problems (if I run VisualStudio 16 2019 as an Admin). Therefore, I have the open62541 folder under `Program files (x86)` with the .h, .dll and .lib files:

[image]

---

The next step is to create the CMake project containing the client code. I used the CMake GUI to link the open62541 files/folders, but I had to do that in my CMakeSetting.json too:

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "open62541.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    UA_Client* client = UA_Client_new();
    UA_Client_delete(client);
    std::cout << "Hello CMake." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("Test")
add_subdirectory ("Test")

# Find the generated/amalgamated header file
find_path(OPEN62541_INCLUDE_DIR open62541.h)

# Find the generated .lib file
find_library(OPEN62541_LIBRARY open62541)

# Find open62541 with dependencies (Full NS0)
find_package(open62541 REQUIRED COMPONENTS FullNamespace)

# Include open62541 include folder 
include_directories(${OPEN62541_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Set open62541 libary 
set(open62541_LIBRARIES ${open62541_LIBRARIES} ${OPEN62541_LIBRARY})

# Create main.exe
add_executable(main "Test/Test.cpp")

# Link open62541 to main. 
target_link_libraries(main ${open62541_LIBRARIES})
```

**CMakeSettings.json**

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "OPEN62541_LIBRARY",
          "value": "C:/Program Files (x86)/open62541/lib/open62541.lib",
          "type": "FILEPATH"
        },
        {
          "name": "OPEN62541_INCLUDE_DIR",
          "value": "C:/Program Files (x86)/open62541/include",
          "type": "PATH"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Problem**

Once I build the project or execute `main.exe`, I get LNK2019 errors for every instance of referenced OPC UA objects:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_UA_Client_delete referenced in function main
```

I tried this using the build examples in the open62541 project too, but with the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

The [installation documentation](https://open62541.org/doc/current/installing.html#manual-installation) describes using an **imported** CMake target to link open62541 to your CMake targets:

> ```
> find_package(open62541 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Events FullNamespace)
> add_executable(main main.cpp)
> target_link_libraries(main open62541::open62541)
> ```

By using the imported target, the following commands in your CMake code become unnecessary:

- `find_path`
- `find_library`
- `include_directories`

In addition, if you haven't done so already, you need to tell CMake *where* to find open62541 on your system. You can do this by appending the path to the generated `open62541Config.cmake` file to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55122281/3987854).

---

Also, it isn't clear what options you ran `cmake` with, but the installation docs suggest running with these options:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DUA_NAMESPACE_ZERO=FULL ..
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my CMakeLists.txt accordingly and rebuilt open62541 again with the options you provided. Still the same issue: I also get an error when I build with the Events flag set.

Comment: I added this to my open62541Config.cmake: `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR})`, where the package prefix dir goes to my open62541 folder as seen in the first picture

Comment: @StephanT. The `list(APPEND ...)` line should be added to your own CMakeLists.txt file before the call to `find_package()`, you should not modify the `open62541Config.cmake` file.

Comment: Ahh, you said "You can do this by appending the path to the generated open62541Config.cmake file", so I thought you meant me to add the line to the cmake file

Comment: @StephanT. Sorry, poorly worded on my part. Meant you need to insert the path at which the open62541Config.cmake file resides *into* the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Same error still persists, I got it to work on Linux though. Sorry for the late reply, I abandoned the project after so many hours of failing. The problem is still showing up after the changes you suggested, so I don't know how to proceed further anymore...